# Occasionally I lose write access to the OS partition and need to fsck it in recovery mode. Why is this happening?

Tags: encryption, swap, fsck, recovery-mode, cryptswap

Ubuntu 17.04, fully encypted hdd, home and swap (partition).
The first time this happened was after cold reset. And happens occasionally ever since. Once every several days or so.

I'm working as normal, while suddenly all crashes because I can't write to the OS partition any more. Reboot goes in recovery mode, where the screenshot is the result of fsck of the OS partition. 
It works fine after that.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/poScH.jpg]

Sorry for the blurry shot, can't take another until it happens again.

```
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
Block bitmap differences
Fix? y
Free blocks count wrong for <number>.
Fix? y
Free blocks count wrong for <another number>.
Fix? y
Free blocks count wrong for <yet another number>.
Fix? y
-- repeats several times --
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: **** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED ****
275223/30154752 files (1.1% non-contiguous), 80789001/120608768 blocks
```

Comment: I had similar error, for me i backup my data did a fresh installation though the disk didnt last for long. I think your disk is getting bad. https://progresscustomersupport-survey.secure.force.com/ProgressKB/articles/Article/P37686

Comment: It's a brand new 512gb NVME ssd in lenovo x1 yoga.

Answer (score 0):

Given this is an SSD (on a platter drive I'd say it was an impending media failure): it's most likely due to an error in the file system that isn't being fully repaired by `fsck`.  Best recommendation I can give is to copy all your data and OS partitions to another device (or clone the drive), then recreate your partitions and restore your OS and data.  You will have to update your `fstab` to reflect the new UUID for each volume after doing this.

Once done, assuming your SSD isn't failing at the hardware level, you should be fixed up.

Comment: Should I still go for full hdd encryption? I have suspicioun that the encrypted swap is causing this.

Comment: Can't give an opinion on that; I've never been paranoid enough to feel I needed to encrypt my storage.